# Swift 5.0: How to fix nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 4 [9: Bad file descriptor] error

Tags: swift, macos, pipe, stdout, executable

**Problem:** 
An error message displayed when I tried to access `stdout` while running a linux executable file inside my MacOS application. The `stdout` messages only appeared much later in blocks.

**Context:** 
I wanted to update my user interface with the data being printed to the XCode console. I tried several tutorials, but I kept getting the same error message that wasn't covered in the material.

**Attempts:** 
I couldn't find any resources that addressed and actually solved this problem.

**Error:**

```
2019-08-09 09:22:21.792908-0700 executable-filename-here[19975:508824] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 4 [9: Bad file descriptor]
2019-08-09 09:22:21.811325-0700 executable-filename-here[19976:508830] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 4 [9: Bad file descriptor]
2019-08-09 09:22:21.819582-0700 executable-filename-here[19977:508836] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 4 [9: Bad file descriptor]
2019-08-09 09:22:21.828539-0700 executable-filename-here[19978:508842] nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 4 [9: Bad file descriptor]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 
I found this solution while implementing a tutorial about intercepting `stdout` in Swift. Although, the article didn't address this error specifically. I noticed the error went away. Apparently, `dup2` helped set the correct file descriptor for `inputPipe` and `outputPipe`. 

[Intercepting stdout in Swift](https://phatbl.at/2019/01/08/intercepting-stdout-in-swift.html) 
[Mac OS X Developer Tools Manual Page For dup2(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/dup2.2.html)

```
import Cocoa

var process = Process()
var inputPipe = Pipe()
var outputPipe = Pipe()

private func runExecutable() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename_here", withExtension: "")
    let arguments = ["argument1", "argument2", "argument3", "etc"]
    process.arguments = arguments
    process.launchPath = url?.path

    // dup2(): Duplicate an existing file descriptor 

    // Copy STDOUT file descriptor to outputPipe for writing strings back to STDOUT
    dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, outputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor)

    // Intercept STDOUT with inputPipe
    dup2(inputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO)

    process.standardInput = inputPipe
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe
    try? process.run()

    // Restore stdout
    freopen("/dev/stdout", "a", stdout)
}
```